# Reconstructing row from record

Tags: postgresql

Based on [Northwind](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/) schema:

Assume we have a query like this (please disregard the actual usefulness of this, as the real use case is more involved)

```
SELECT unnest(r.agg) FROM (
  SELECT array_agg(x) AS agg
  FROM (
     SELECT *
     FROM northwind.u_suppliers s LEFT JOIN northwind.u_products p ON s.guid = p.supplier
     ) x
  GROUP BY x.supplier
  ) r LIMIT 1;
```

the result is

```
(9Y_03ogA1mOixVtJTqB8zih9Lu5-DB-l--fYvnHhyMQ,22,"Dirk Luchte","Accounting Manager",6j7qZ3Pjad5irKAM1MKX1WU7hvkgIOhZoe9OeRfTX4Q,"(12345) 1210",,northwindSupplier,jp9VvzFBbklHelD_ybS1oDsJbILda1duNhMtCdGBZqg,0,do4_k8zCsOog5tYROlsouF81Uj9I5LbTFawvuPw9Q-0,"2017-10-11 08:45:14.982",47,"Zaanse koeken",9Y_03ogA1mOixVtJTqB8zih9Lu5-DB-l--fYvnHhyMQ,AkOUoKYOpHFWIkNcoPX3CLtTl4n_ACN6TwWxqd3gzYQ,"10 - 4 oz boxes",9.5,36,0,0,f,,northwindProduct)
```

which is a record.

What would be the way to create a table from this with all columns and unnested records as rows?

So there'd be:

```
u_suppliers_column1 | ... | u_suppliers.columnN | u_products.column1 | ... | u_products.columnN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
9Y_03og...          | 22 | "Dirk Luchte" ...
```

The snippet is for illustrational purpose only - of course, creating aggregate just to unnest it again is non-sensible under these circumstances, but for sake of simplicity & reproducibility I have decided to write it as such,.

Comment: I mentioned the real use case is more involved. Question is related how to create a row from that record. I wanted to have snippet that's easily reproducible for readers.

Comment: I think yo uneed to cast the record to a matching type, with `unnest(r.agg)::some_type` and then expand it to a row: `(unnest(r.agg)::some_type).*`. The type should have the same column types as that `x` derived table.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Thanks - that does work! Is it possible though, without creating manually type of the "joined" tables to specify `some_type`? If there was no join, I could simply do `::u_suppliers` and it would work.

Comment: @KadekM I don't know, perhaps there is. In the mean time, you can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: No, it's not possible because the database needs to know the columns of the result **before** it runs the query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name true but still. The columns come from the `u_suppliers LEFT JOIN u_products`. It would be handy to have a syntax - same way we can do `unnest(r.agg)::some_table` - something like: `unnest(tr.agg)::TYPE(a_table JOIN b_table)`

Comment: And I k onw it's not trivial, not with all the different types of join (with `ON` or `USING`, `NATURAL` joins) that produce different number of columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @ypercubeᵀᴹ , one can go about it by first creating intermediary type with all the required columns (from both tables, since it's join) such as:

```
CREATE TYPE suppliers_products AS (s_guid VARCHAR(64), supplierId, ...)
```

The following query can be then written such as:

```
SELECT (unnest(r.agg)).*
  FROM (
     SELECT array_agg(x :: suppliers_products) AS agg
     FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM northwind.u_suppliers S LEFT JOIN northwind.u_products p ON S.guid = p.supplier
          ) x
     GROUP BY x.supplier
   ) r
  LIMIT 1;
```

If there was no anonymous record (coming from join), we would not need intermediate type.

As far as I'm aware there is no way to do it without manually preparing such type upfront.